# Get value from ruby key, from other ruby key value

Tags: ruby

Lets say I have the following in an array:

```
[
  {:region=>"beta", :db=>"CLIENTDB1"},
  {:region=>"prod", :db=>"CLIENTDB2"},
  {:region=>"train", :db=>"CLIENTDB3"}
]
```

I want to be able to call the variable and get the value `beta`, by saying that db = CLIENTDB1. Kinda like a sql statement that would do, "select region where db = CLIENTDB1"

Also, I am on ruby 1.8.7, so .key won't work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
@var.find {|h| h[:db] == 'CLIENTDB1'}[:region]
```